# How to sync Upsource comments with GitLab discussions

Tags: gitlab, integration, upsource

I have integrated Upsource with Gitlab, by providing OAuth details, now I'm able to fetch the repository, all merge requests and any comments which are happening with an active MR.

But if I'm writing a message from Upsource, it doesn't synchronise back with Gitlab, and users from Gitlab can't see my comments. Is there a way to fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JetBrains twitter, there’s a GitLab API limitation that prevents them from fixing this issue. This is expected behavior.

https://twitter.com/upsource_jb/status/1042068438993326082